# How to detect double-taps on cells "only for a single finger" in a UICollectionView?

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UICollectionView` containing lots of cells.

There are two features I implemented:

1. **Singly tap a cell**: push A view.
2. **Doubly tap a cell**: push B view.

Here's the problem:

If I singly tap two cells (or more) simultaneously, it only push **1** A view. It's ok in this scenario.

However, if I doubly tap two cells (or more) simultaneously, it push **2 (or more)** B views one by one. This causes unexpected behavior and the app will sometimes crash.

How can I **disable other cells to receive doubly tap** while there're more than 2 cells being tapped, and **only allow "1 B view" to be pushed**?

I add `doubleTapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1`, but it's not work.

Here's my code:

```swift
@objc private func didReceiveDoubleTap(_ sender: ASCellNode) {
  self.doubleTapDelegate?.myCellWasDoubleTapped?(self)
}

override func didLoad() {
  super.didLoad()

  let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyCollectionCell.didReceiveDoubleTap(_:)))
  doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
  doubleTapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = true
  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can prevent calling the delegate method multiple times with a boolean check.

```
@objc private func didReceiveDoubleTap(_ sender: ASCellNode) {
  if !processing {
    processing = true // set processing = false where it's safe to do so.
    self.doubleTapDelegate?.myCellWasDoubleTapped?(self)
  }
}
```